How to show a String + today's date in a the email subject using Mailapp.sendemail in Apps Script?
The code is pretty much done but I want to include today's date in the subject. What do I have to add to "const subject" in order to accomplish this? I've already defined today's date as "today"
the code is in the image, please see the highlighted part
See image code
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A17:dm");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  i=0; //i & j is the row number (up/down)
  j=3;

    const col = data[j];
    const row = data[i];
    const machinetype = row[84]; //the 84 is how far you are going to the right, add 4 to each when re-running it
    const machinemodel = col[84];
    const emailAddress = "djas@molusvs.com";
    const subject = "New Machine";


   const message = createEmailMessage(machinetype, machinemodel);
function createEmailMessage(machinetype, machinemodel) {
  const message = `Hi Dhariana,

A new machine has arrived at the shop. It is a ${machinemodel}... a ${machinetype} machine.

Kindly schedule the cleaning procedure.

Thank you. 

Best,
`;

  return message;
}

    try {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      console.log(` Email sent to ${emailAddress}`);
      console.log(`${machinetype}, ${machinemodel}`);
    } catch (error) {
      
    }
  
}


Append new Date to a string
Since your today variable is already a string because of Utilities.formatDate() (see image below) you can just easily append it to a string(your subject) using the following ways:
Using + symbol
const subject = "New machine "+today

or
Using String literals
const subject = `New Machine ${today}`

Data type of today variable

Sample Output

Reference: Utilities.formatDate
